# Docker Compose: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker-compose to fetch, build and run multiple services from their git repositories. I made a simple docker-compose.yml to test it:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test-service:
    build: git@gitlab.com:dan-poltherm/partservicego.git
    ports:
      - 8005:443
```

It seems that docker-compose can't fetch repository I get following error when calling `docker-compose up --build`:

```
ERROR: error fetching: fatal: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
```

I have OpenSSH Client installed (Windows 10 port) and `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\` added to PATH, I also set `GIT_SSH` to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`. I can clone repo with `git clone` and `ssh` also works from powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) is a way to go

Comment: Repository is private, so I'd have to either: include my gitlab login and password in compose file, which I obviously can't do or place them in env variable which I shouldn't do either. I have my ssh-agent running as a service which is why I want to access repo using ssh.

Comment: What is the use case of this? If you are running docker for development only on your machine, then just use some environmental variable. If you distribute it to someone else as an image, then they will see contents of private repo. If you use it for deployment, then maybe use Personal access token. p.s. https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/

Comment: I'm running docker for both development and deployment, I have multiple microservices, and I want to be able to run each in isolation, mostly for ease of development, so I don't want to pull them from their repositories in Dockerfile because in that case I'd have to include multiple required Dockerfiles in every possible development configuration. Access token provided thorugh env variable sounds like a good option though.

Comment: I tested access token and it works very well. If you edit your answer to use access token I will gladly accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, **"build:"** is the path where your Dockerfile is located.

I would suggest to checkout the repository, and put the docker-compose.yml inside the folder.

Then change your docker-compose.yml to:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test-service:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8005:443
```

From the docs (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

> build can be specified either as a string containing a path to the
>   build context:

Comment: "build" can point to url for what I know (https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2430) I could pull each repo individually if I had 2 of them, but keeping 10 of them up to date would be annoying, and what if I had more? That'd be extremely inefficient.