# GitHub repository to build a service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have to use a private GitHub repository to build the service `example`. I added the `not_so_private_id_rsa` as a deploy key in the GitHub repo.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
 db:
  ...
 web:
  ...
 example:
  build: git@github.com:example/example.git
  volumes:
   - '~/.ssh/not_so_private_id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

When I run `docker-compose build` on a macOS 10.15 (Catalina) I get this error:

```
$ docker-compose build
Building example
ERROR: error fetching: error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
: exit status 128
```

### Questions

1. Is this the right way to use a private GitHub repository within `docker-compose.yml`?
2. How can I fix it?

PS: I am aware of [Docker Compose: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734337/docker-compose-cannot-run-ssh-no-such-file-or-directory) but it contains no solution for my problem.

Comment: what happens when you run `which ssh` and `ssh` in your terminal; is `ssh` installed?

Comment: @xarantolus /usr/bin/ssh

Comment: @xarantolus ssh works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can’t specify detailed build instructions like this only within `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 1):

By far the best way to do this is to clone the repository on your host machine.  Often you can commit the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` to the repository, and then everything will be in one place.

```
git clone git@github.com:example/example
cd example
docker-compose up --build
```

Running `git clone` in the Dockerfile has several major problems.  The standard `docker build` layer caching will skip over a command it thinks it’s already run, so you’re prone to missing current commits.  You can very reasonably want to build an image that’s based on uncommitted code or is on a branch, which is hard to express in an external Dockerfile.  But the biggest problem is the credentials.

The path you show won’t work because the `build:` and `volumes:` lines are considered in two separate steps.  You have to use a multi-stage build to be able to check out the repository, but not leak the credentials to other people who might get a copy of your image.  This could roughly look like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS checkout
ARG commit=master
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      git-core \
      openssh-client
COPY .ssh /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 0400 /root/.ssh/*
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone git@github.com:example/example \
 && cd example \
 && git checkout $commit

FROM something
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=checkout /app/example .
...
```

Even then, you need an ssh keypair in the local build directory (which you’ll have to manually copy in) and you need to be careful to not accidentally `COPY` it into the final image.

Comment: How can I do it within the docker-compose.yml system? I have several services which I'd like to build at the same time.

Comment: You can’t specify detailed build instructions like this only within `docker-compose.yml`.  If you have all of your repositories checked out locally, you can say things like `build: ../service-x` to build the individual images.